# Why does my clock applet calendar appear in the wrong place?

Tags: 10.10, applet, clock

I have a clock applet on the right hand side of a panel at the bottom of my screen. When I click on it for some reason the calendar box appears at the top right hand corner and is partially off the screen. As you might imagine this is quite annoying and limits its usefulness. How can I make it appear in the correct place?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with Compiz in Maverick. I had the same problem when I upgraded, since my panel was also on the bottom of the screen.

The relevant bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/631664

The workaround I used was to open the Compiz config Settings manager (if you don't have it on your preferences menu: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`) to force the window to open near the bottom.
From comment #10 by Kantastisk in the thread of the aforementioned bug:

> Go to the "Place Windows" plugin of ccsm and under the tab "Fixed Window Placement" find the box "Windows with fixed positions" and click "new". Select the + icon and under "Type" choose "window title". Click your calendar applet, then the "grab" button and then click your open calendar. The resulting value should be something like "title=Calendar" or whatever it is in your language. Click add and under x and y positions choose the farthest settings to the right. Finally check "Keep in workarea" and you should be good to go.

Without using CCSM, there is supposedly a quick way (I did not try it) via the terminal posted by Zamiere Vonthokikkeiin (again in the thread of the aforementioned bug):

> ```
> gconftool-2 -t list -s --list-type=bool /apps/compiz/plugins/place/screen0/options/position_constrain_workarea [true]
> gconftool-2 -t list -s --list-type=string /apps/compiz/plugins/place/screen0/options/position_matches ["name=clock-applet"]
> gconftool-2 -t list -s --list-type=int /apps/compiz/plugins/place/screen0/options/position_x_values [32767]
> gconftool-2 -t list -s --list-type=int /apps/compiz/plugins/place/screen0/options/position_y_values [32767]
> ```

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thank you very much for your help.